# Position an element relative to it's original position except for x=0

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to position an element relative to it's original position, except for x=0 - that is, the element is positioned at it's original vertical coordinate but is glued to the window's left border?

Comment: You can always use javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, yes.

I believe the term is going to be "sticky".
It will say: this element is positioned relatively, until it passes a specific threshold, and then it will be a fixed-position, located at... wherever

I think there was some preliminary support in mobile (for things like responsive menus/headers), and the webkit developer branch.

For real-world support, you're best off to just use JavaScript.